# sqlite3 python inner join syntax

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a customer and orders table for a demo project using SQLITE3 and Python 3.  I am trying to select data from both the CUSTOMER and ORDERS table.

CUSTOMERID is a foreign key on the ORDERS table.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('promhire.db')
print("Opened database successfully")

cursor = conn.execute ('''\
            SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID, ORDERS.CUSTOMERID ORDERS.ORDERDATE CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERS.FIRSTNAME
            FROM ORDERS
            INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS
            ON ORDERS.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID
            WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID = 1''')
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
conn.close()
```

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHot.png)

The error I am getting is

```
"OperationalError: near ".": syntax error"
Highlighting the last line of SQL.
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmGHd.png)

Any ideas how to code this correctly for Python?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add the source and the error message as text.

Comment: it will be good if you add source code and error message as text in question itself.

Comment: Thanks I have done.

Answer (score 1):

check comma ("`,`") in query

```
select orders.orderid, orders.customerid,orders.orderdate,customers.customerid,customers.firstname from orders ..
```

Edit :

```
cursor = conn.execute ('''\
            SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID, ORDERS.CUSTOMERID, ORDERS.ORDERDATE, CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID, CUSTOMERS.FIRSTNAME
            FROM ORDERS
            INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS
            ON ORDERS.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID
            WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID = 1''')
```

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the commas in the select statement but get the same error.

Comment: @LucyBunce : Don't remove commas, add it in proper place

Comment: Thanks so much Harsha!